# Set user defined time for time.h

Tags: c, date, time

I am working on an embedded system where I need to calculate current date and time. I need to take leap years and all under consideration. Instead of reinventing all algorithms I thought using functions from `time.h` would fit great.

The problem is that I am not sure how I can set the current time in the `time.h`. It doesn't have its own reference, since there is even no operating system in my project. Can it be done somehow?

Comment: You cannot set current time with any function in time.h, this is not in the scope of the C standard library. If your board has a real time clock, the hardware documentation should document methods of setting it up.

Comment: I know how to setup the relative time in my board. The problem is I need a reference to epoch time and that I need to calculate all by myself. I thought I could use the `time.h` in order not to implement all the conversions by hand.

Comment: A POSIX function clock_settime is declared in time.h on POSIX systems. This however is not standard C and your bare metal C implementation is most probably not POSIX conformant. Still it could provide the function as an extension.

Comment: "I need a reference to epoch time" Your C implementation is probanly hardcoded to some epoch, most likely the Unix epoch. If so you will have to set the time relative to the midnight of January 1st 1970.

Comment: Thats right, But `time` function wont return seconds since epoch since the module doesnt know what time is it.

Comment: "the module doesnt know what time is it." You have said earlier that you know how to set time on the board. What does it mean if not a method to tell the board what time is it?

Comment: I know what Time it is, but the `time` function from `time.h` does not. If I could tell the `time.h` what time it is (normally it knows it from the OS) then this would work.

Comment: Please explain precisely what the sentence "I know how to setup the relative time in my board" means. What is the state of the system before and after you do the procedure?

Comment: There is no procedure yet. I have a current time saved in the local (safe made) struct. Thus, I know the time and the `time.h` module does not, thus I cannot use it for anything.

Comment: Setting the time is a procedure that changes the state of the clock. Querying the state of the clock is fine and dandy, but without an ability to synchronise the clock to some external reference, it cannot be used to query current time. If you in fact don't know how to set the time, you need to figure it out from the board documentation.

Comment: This is not about setting the time on the board... This question is simply about setting the time for the `time` module from the `time.h` library, thats all, no further philosophy in it. This question is completely hardware abstract.

Comment: There is no such thing as "setting the time for the time module". The C library doesn't provide such interface. All ways to set the time lie completely outside of the C standard library. Absent an OS, the only method do set the time would be hardware-dependent. You wish to make the question hardware-independent, and you can, if you are able to take "no" for an answer. Otherwise you need to deal with hardware.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: How does `time.h` knows what time is it? If it is checking in some kind of memory location or register, then what is this register? I will set it with current time.

Comment: The details are implementation dependent, but normally, absent an OS, time.h (assuming it works at all) queries some device in a hardware-dependent manner. Did I mention you need to deal with your particular hardware? You do, you really do.

Comment: In the end, yes I do. But for this moment, I need to know how does `time.h` "querry the hardware". At the moment it does not, at all, and I want to make him do that.

Comment: *I need to know how does time.h "querry the hardware". At the moment it does not, at all". So your implementation doesn't provide a working `time.h`. Thank you, that was a great way to spend a morning. You need to read your hardware manual (did I mention you cannot avoid studying your hardware?) and write a functioning implementation of one or more `time.h` functions.

Comment: Look... I am already handling the time using hardware. Now I want to connect it to "not working" `time.h`. This is what I was trying to explain all the time.

Comment: You are doing an extremely poor job of explaining it. Sorry. Communicate the **facts**. Let's start with basic facts. Do any of the following time.h functions --- ctime, asctime, gmtime, localtime --- work, in the sense of returning progressively advancing time values?

Comment: No, they do not, because they are not connected with my hardware at any point.

Comment: Sorry this set of functions is a mental glitch. I meant one single function `time`. If it doesn't advance, your implementation doesn't interface with the hardware. If this is the case, you want to provide your own `time` function that implements the interface described in `man 2 time` (returns time in seconds after 00h00m January 1st 1970). How you write this function depends on your hardware. Then the other functions that receive the `time_t` argument might work. Then again they might not, as there's probably no timezone data, but at least  `gmtime` and `asctime` may work. No guarantees.

Comment: Ok, but is there way to not implement the own `time` function, but somehow provide time reference for the existing `time` function from `time.h`? The 1time1 function at low level of implementation read the epoch. I assume it doesnt know where to read the epoch from. I could provide that, but I dont know how.

Comment: The way existing `time` function works is unspecified. There is no way to provide any sort of reference for it. In your implementation it may be implemented as `{return 0;}` for all we know.

Comment: Ok, All I wanted to know. To bad, thank you. PS: for me it returns -1 by default.